# loadView after popViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, loadview, popviewcontrolleranimated

Alright, so I have this project with 2 ViewControllers connected with eachother with a NavigationController. When I navigate to each VC it all loads properly and my loadView method is called as proper. But when I navigate back this loadView method is not being called.

How can I make my VC do their loadView method right after I popped the VC that was on top of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the main rootViewController is called `- (void)viewDidLoad` is called.

After that any other popping & pushing back to this rootViewController, try putting your methods in View did appear method `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: I found my error there and why it didn't load my VC properly. Your answer is the solution to the problem yet it didn't seemed to be in my programming structure. I adjusted it and it works properly now.